# imwrite OpenCV not writing an image in ec2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, opencv, image-processing, amazon-ec2

I am reading an image which is stored on my ec2 instance and then adding some text to it and writing the image back!
However no image come in the path i have specified to write the image.

```
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path,imgName), temp_img12)
```

Are there some kind of write permissions needed to write an image on ec2 instance?

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: Can you please store the output of `cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path,imgName), temp_img12)` in a variable and check if it is `True` or `False` ? If it is `False`, there could be some problem with `temp_img12`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was chmod issue, the file was not given write access.
thanks for the comments but sadly imwrite does not give any error messages just a true or false if image was written or not.